# Google Analytics: Change userID at runtime in a SPA

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, web-analytics, universal-analytics

The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/user-id) indicates that the userId must be set this way:

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-Y', { 'userId': 'USER_ID' });
```

But in a Single Page Application (SPA), the user starts as anonymous and then logs in. So the app will start with:

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-Y', 'auto');
```

And when he logs in, then I would like to change to a specific ID for tracking that user, but when I try:

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-Y', { 'userId': 'USER_ID' });
```

Nothing happens, the user ID does not appears in subsequent requests.

Which is the right way of setting the userId at runtime?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, the documentation is currently incorrect. It **is** possible to set the user ID outside of the `create` method.

The reason your example isn't working is because you're calling `create` twice. What you want to do is call `set`. Here's how:

```
// Create the tracker instance.
ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-Y', 'auto');

// Once you know the user ID, set it on the current tracker.
ga('set', { userId: USER_ID });
```

Now all subsequent hits sent to GA will be associated with this user ID.

**UPDATE:**

The [user ID documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#userId) now reflects that it can be set outside of the `create` method.

Comment: While it _is_ possible to set it outside of the create method, I wouldn't recommend it. Just have it as `ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-Y', 'auto', {userID: 'USER ID'});`

Comment: @MisterPhilip your suggestion won't work here because the OP doesn't know the user ID at create time.

Comment: Yup just noting that the set method may or may not work as expected in the long run.

Comment: @MisterPhilip using `set` with `userId` is officially supported.

Comment: Thanks! it works great. Can you please point me where I may find this in the documentation? Thanks.

Comment: @vtortola https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#userId

Comment: Is there a way to do the same with GA4? [Setting](https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/gtagjs/reference#set) `user_id` seems to have no effect.